# Use Eclipse Auto Completion Like Pre 4.5

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I don't know about you, but I used to work with the Eclipse templates like `syso` for `System.out.println(...)` and `lazy` for a lazy initialization a lot until Eclipse 4.5.

For whatever reason they it's now broken (I'm not sure about the version it stopped working, but must be late 4.5 or early 4.6). Or it works differently and we can't seem to figure out how. So first what we found out:

The default options of the "Content Assist" -> "Advanced" preference page don't work at all. You need to uncheck the "Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)" to make something like content assist work again.

The first time you use content assist and save a file, "Adaptive Template Proposals (Code Recommenders)", "Chain Proposals (Code Recommenders)" and "Java Proposals" get unchecked, but "Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)" get checked. Since this don't work (see above) you need to uncheck it (again) and check the correct "Java Proposals".

No matter the ordering of "Template Proposals" on the bottom table, some of the templates are displayed on the bottom of the list. Like `lazy` is always displayed below all classes that contain "Lazy". Similarly `systrace` is always only displayed on the second page.

I'm perceived 100% slower because I can't use `System.outs` and so on like I used to, so I'm wondering if there is any way to make the content assist work like before 4.5. Or at least get the templates to show on the top of the list. Or at the very least stop Eclipse from checking and unchecking items on the preference page on a whim.

(We have a wide range of OS (but all Windows7+) and Eclipse versions (but all 4.5+ and installed Eclipse plug-ins, have older workspaces and brand new ones, and we couldn't find any correlation between anything beyond "it does not work for anybody").

Comment: My guess is this is probably the 'Code Recommenders' plugins which I believe are now included in most downloads (and which weren't included in older releases). Personally I use one of the smaller Eclipse Project downloads and only include a few extra plugins - 'sysou' works fine for me. Possibly uninstalling 'code recommenders' will help.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm not sure if this is supposed to work, but uninstalling the Code Recommenders features makes Eclipse pretend to do something, and after a restart of the application they're still present. But good idea to start again with one of the smaller downloads.

Comment: @greg-449 I finally came around to creating Eclipse from scratch. No Oomph, and this time Code Recommenders could be deinstalled. And it works (even though its weird that before the template would recognize `syst`, now I have to write at least `systr`, but I'm not picky at this point).